# Dundalk Ireland to Newry Northern Ireland with Bus Eireann, is a COVID test required for an unvaccinated person?

Tags: uk, covid-19, ireland, road-trips, northern-ireland

When travelling from Dundalk Ireland to Newry Northern Ireland with Bus Eireann, is a COVID test required for an unvaccinated person?

Comment: I wonder… How is it even possible for people not to be vaccinated?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! If you want information on how to get vaccinated in Ireland or Northern Ireland for travel purposes, we’re happy to answer that too in a separate question.

Comment: There is passport control dundalk to newry by road with eireann bus

Answer (score 6):

The [Bus Eireann COVID-19 Update page](https://www.buseireann.ie/inner.php?id=711) says that you will have to wear a face mask, in line with Government guidance. (Unless you are exempt) There are no requirements for testing or vaccination.

However, if you are staying overnight in Northern Island, you [are advised to take a LFD test](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/coronavirus-covid-19-travelling-within-common-travel-area):

> **If you're travelling from within the Common Travel Area (CTA) and staying overnight in Northern Ireland, you should take a rapid lateral flow device test (LFD) before you begin your journey.**
>
> You should only travel if the test is negative.
>
> You should also take an LFD test on days two and eight of your stay.
>
> You should not travel to Northern Ireland if you have COVID-19 symptoms, or have received a positive COVID-19 result.

You will also need to [fill in a passenger locator form](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk) if you have been outside the Common Travel Area (United Kingdom, Republic of Ireland, Isle of Man, and Channel Islands) in the past 10 days.